# How can I simplify code with f"{}" Python

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to simplify my code, I did it via f"{}". But now I need when you click on certainly item, to switch a screen with certain number. But I don't know how. Are there any possibilities?

```
def show_bottom_sheet(self):
    bs = MDListBottomSheet()
    bs.add_item("bla bla", lambda x: x,icon='account-group-outline')

    for y in 1,2,3,4,12,13:

        bs.add_item(f"number {y} ", lambda x: self.behavior(), icon='account-group-outline'.format(y))
        bs.open()
```

instead of

```
    #bs.add_item("2", lambda x: self.behavior2(), icon='account-group-outline')
    #bs.add_item("3", lambda x: self.behavior3(),icon='account-group-outline' )
    #bs.add_item("4", lambda x: self.behavior4(),icon='account-group-outline' )
    #bs.add_item("12", lambda x: self.behavior12(),icon='account-group-outline' )
    #bs.add_item("13", lambda x: self.behavior13(), icon='account-group-outline')
```

I tried something like this but unsuccessful:

```
def behavior(self):
    for y in 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13:
        self.manager.current = f"{y}"
```

I had it before like this

```
def behavior2(self):
    self.manager.current = "2"
def behavior3(self):
    self.manager.current = "3"
def behavior4(self):
    self.manager.current = "4"
def behavior12(self):
    self.manager.current = "12"
def behavior13(self):
    self.manager.current = "13"
def behavior14(self):
```

Comment: A Python dictionary could be an option for your problem, you could use it like a switch statements in other programming languages

Comment: Instead of `f"{y}"` you could use `str(y)`

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `behavior()` method needs to take a parameter:

```py
bs.add_item(f"number {y} ", lambda x: self.behavior(x), icon='account-group-outline'.format(y))

...

def behavior(self, x):
    self.manager.current = f"{x}"
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\Stanko\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1064, in get_screen
     raise ScreenManagerException('No Screen with name "%s".' % name)
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "<kivymd.uix.list.OneLineIconListItem object at 0x0ADB1C58>".

Comment: it shows me this error, can you help me please?